# What Combobox Event is Used When Applying a Row Filter?

Tags: vb.net, events, combobox, rowfilter

### Goal

I want to learn what event is raised on `ComboBox1` when `ComboBox2`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` creates a **RowFilter** on `ComboBox1`'s **DataView**.

---

### Current Issue

I have two comboboxes with their DataSources set to two different DataViews (`ProgramDataView` & `CategoryDataView`). My DataViews tables are populated correctly and the ComboBox's DisplayMembers & ValueMembers are also set correctly.

Here's what I get at first:

[image: Both comboxes successfully loaded]

And then I modifiy the "Category" section, which sets a row filter on the Program DataView (meaning it shows only the programs who have the category **Mécanique**

[image: Row Filter applied]

---

### Events I have tried

Here are the events I have tried:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged / SelectedValueChanged / SelectionChangeCommitted / Validated
```

Any ideas what could make the ComboBox1 trigger an event whenever it's DataView's RowFilter is modified?